# Removing brackets [ ] and comma Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, brackets

I'm trying to sort the list in ascending order by student last name and display the list but I want to remove the [, ] that return null. Is there a way I am able to not see that.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentTest  {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
        
        

       list.add(new Student(" Gracia", "50","\tCOP2250, COP3250, COP4250"));
       list.add(new Student(" Jones", "30", "\tCOP1210, COP3337, COP3530"));
       list.add(new Student(" Smith", "10", "\tCOP2250, COP3250, COP4250"));
       list.add(new Student(" Wilson", "20", "\tWNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210"));
       list.add(new Student(" Braga", "10", "\tENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250"));
       list.add(new Student(" Adams", "20", "\tWNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210"));
       list.add(new Student(" Giron", "60","\tCOP1210, COP3337, COP3530"));
       list.add(new Student(" O'Neal", "45","\tENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210"));
       list.add(new Student(" Ervin", "40",  "\tENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250"));
       list.add(new Student(" Bourne", "70","\tCOP2250, ENC3250, COP3530"));
   
       
        System.out.println(list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
        
    }
}

class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    

    public Student(String name, String id, String course) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getName() {
        
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

  
    public Student(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String course;
    
  
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student student) {
           
        return name.compareTo(student.name);
        
    }

    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        

       System.out.println("" + id + name + course );
        
        return "";
                              
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

> 10 Smith  COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
>
> 20 Wilson WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
>
> 10 Braga  ENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250
>
> 20 Adams  WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
>
> 60 Giron  COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
>
> 45 O'Neal ENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
>
> 40 Ervin  ENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250
>
> 70 Bourne COP2250, ENC3250, COP3530
>
> [, , , , , , , , , ]

Why am I getting this line?

> [, , , , , , , , , ]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify, what do you mean by *"I want to remove the [, ] that return null"*.

Comment: Sure...iterate through the **list** array properly. Try using a **for** loop.

Comment: output is as follows:
20 Adams WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
70 Bourne COP2250, ENC3250, COP3530
10 Braga ENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250
40 Ervin ENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250
60 Giron COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
50 Gracia COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
30 Jones COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
45 O'Neal ENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
10 Smith COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
20 Wilson WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
[, , , , , , , , , ]

Comment: I am also unsure about what you want, but the point of the `toString` method on an object is to return a string representation not printing it and then return `""`. Maybe consider changing it to return the data instead of printing it. For more information, you can check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 1):

When you do `System.out.println(list);` You just use a default implementation of `ArrayList.toString()` method which returns values in the list in the [] brackets separated by comma and space.
You have two options there:

1. Iterate through the list on your own and print each Student individually (as long as it has it's `toString()` method implementation.
2. Or you can use replaceAll() for the String you have now from `list.toString()`

First option is preferable in general, because for common case `"[" "]" ", "` can be valid characters inside the list elements and must not be replaced.
But, for small case when you are sure there will be no such characters in `Student name, id or course` you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `System.out.println(list)` you are using the default implementation of the List to print something to the console.

The default implementation iterates over your list and calls the toString of each object. It was a good idea to override that function in you Student class. But you are just returning "". The default implementation creates a new String. It starts with a "[". It will be followed by the return value of the toString method of every object inside the list (seperated by ","). It ends with a "]". Your toString method returns an empty String "". That means the default implementation will create the following:

> [, , , , , , , , , ]

You can now change the return value of your toString method:

```
public String toString() {
   return "" + id + name + course ;
}
```

Than you will get the following output:

> [50 Gracia    COP2250, COP3250, COP4250, 30 Jones COP1210, COP3337, COP3530, 10 Smith COP2250, COP3250, COP4250, 20 Wilson    WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210, 10 Braga ENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250, 20 Adams WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210, 60 Giron COP1210, COP3337, COP3530, 45 O'Neal    ENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210, 40 Ervin ENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250, 70 Bourne    COP2250, ENC3250, COP3530]

If you don't want to have the commatars and brackets you can write your own list, which extends from ArrayList, or you iterate over your list, instead of printing it.

```
   for(Student s : list){
       System.out.println(s);
   }
```

Then you will get the following output:

> 50 Gracia    COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
>
> 30 Jones  COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
>
> 10 Smith  COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
>
> 20 Wilson WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
>
> 10 Braga  ENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250
>
> 20 Adams  WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
>
> 60 Giron  COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
>
> 45 O'Neal ENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
>
> 40 Ervin  ENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250
>
> 70 Bourne COP2250, ENC3250, COP3530

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the square brackets when listing your **list** ArrayList array then don't just use:

```
System.out.println(list);
```

You should iterate through the array so as to process each array element the way you want, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Now there are no square brackets.

Your **main()** method code should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(new Student(" Gracia", "50", "\tCOP2250, COP3250, COP4250"));
    list.add(new Student(" Jones", "30", "\tCOP1210, COP3337, COP3530"));
    list.add(new Student(" Smith", "10", "\tCOP2250, COP3250, COP4250"));
    list.add(new Student(" Wilson", "20", "\tWNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210"));
    list.add(new Student(" Braga", "10", "\tENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250"));
    list.add(new Student(" Adams", "20", "\tWNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210"));
    list.add(new Student(" Giron", "60", "\tCOP1210, COP3337, COP3530"));
    list.add(new Student(" O'Neal", "45", "\tENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210"));
    list.add(new Student(" Ervin", "40", "\tENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250"));
    list.add(new Student(" Bourne", "70", "\tCOP2250, ENC3250, COP3530"));

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }

    Collections.sort(list);

    System.out.println(""); 
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Now, as @Leon has already stated within his comment, you have set up your **toString()** method incorrectly within the **Student** class. You should be returning data as a string rather than displaying it. Your **toString()** method should look like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return id + name + course;
}
```

And that should take care of things. Your output should look like:

```
50 Gracia   COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
30 Jones    COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
10 Smith    COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
20 Wilson   WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
10 Braga    ENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250
20 Adams    WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
60 Giron    COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
45 O'Neal   ENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
40 Ervin    ENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250
70 Bourne   COP2250, ENC3250, COP3530

20 Adams    WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
70 Bourne   COP2250, ENC3250, COP3530
10 Braga    ENC1105, ENC3250, ISO4250
40 Ervin    ENC1105, COP3250, ISO4250
60 Giron    COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
50 Gracia   COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
30 Jones    COP1210, COP3337, COP3530
45 O'Neal   ENC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
10 Smith    COP2250, COP3250, COP4250
20 Wilson   WNC1105, ENC3250, REL2210
```

Comment: I knew I needed a for loop somewhere just wasn't clicking, I blame the weekend! Thanks again this worked amazingly fine.